Which statistical approach is best for diverse conversion rates in an A/B test?
Our software startup builds chat bots for ecommerce websites. The chatbot talks to customers that open the chat bot, and has the goal of closing the sale with the store’s main product. We have about 100 active ecommerce stores using our chat bot. Chat bot conversations either result in a sale or don’t, so the metric we are optimizing for is the conversion rate for each store.
We want to run A/B tests on the chat bot across all stores to measure improvements in conversion rate. Our goal is to introduce changes that maximize conversion rate as a whole across all types of stores (big/small, no matter what product category).
Here are the main considerations that make our scenario tricky:

Each store has a different intrinsic conversion rate since our stores are of all types of categories and have different customer demographics

We only have 100 active stores, which is a rather small sample size. However, across all 100 stores, we have about 300k unique user conversations weekly, about 10k of those conversations convert

Stores vary drastically in weekly conversations and conversion rate. Some stores have 50k conversations a week, others may only have 1k a week. Average and median weekly conversations per store is 2000 and 230 respectively.

We want to make changes in our chat bot that positively affect all stores


What would be the best approach for this? Hierarchical modeling? Bayesian? Frequentist? Or something special?

How do you randomize treatment? Is it at customer-level? Or store-level?

Or product-level?

"We want to make changes in our chat bot that positively affect all stores" Can you explain this more precisely. You want a single change that works on average for all stores? How do you make this average (eg improvements inost stores or in most customers, etc)? Or do you want to make tailor made changes that are different for different stores?

What would be wrong with just choosing with whatever method works best? Or do you have additional considerations. For example, like implementing a change being costly and you want to know to estimate a probability that such change is worthwhile?

@dimitriy that's TBD, I'm looking for the best approach

@SextusEmpiricus we want to make single, iterative changes to our chat bot that boost conversion rate across all stores. Choosing which variant is best is non trivial

"introduce changes that maximize conversion rate" I dont see how this is not trivial. Why not just compute the conversion rate and choose the highest case? What is the problem that you encounter here? Could you explain why it is not trivial.

@SextusEmpiricus dealing with cross contamination, statistical significance, and then the key part of the question: hierchical vs bayesian vs frequentist

Why is statistical significance important? That sounds like your goal is more complex than described.

@SextusEmpiricus have you run an a/b test before?

Yes I have run such tests before.

please edit your question to define mathematically what  you want to optimise. then the statistical questions can be looked at. eg total conversion rate across all stores, average conversion  rate of each store, average conversion rate of each product/store combination etc


Our goal is to introduce changes that maximize conversion rate as a whole across all types of stores.

If this is your goal, then you do not need statistics like computation of significance. You just compute the conversion rate for the different interventions and the standard and choose the option whichever is best.
It are additional aspects that make that you need more statistics. For example, if implementing a change is costly, or if in some other way the choices/changes have a different cost, then you may want to optimize the expectation value of the choice, and for this you need to know/estimate probabilities of outcomes with different choices.

What would be the best approach for this? Hierarchical modeling? Bayesian? Frequentist? Or something special?

There is no single best approach. To decide which is best you need to specify more precisely the cost function that you wish to optimize and the uncertainties that play a role in estimating the model that is used to compute an optimum.

What do you think about using randomization inference here? That entails a sharp null hypothesis of no effect for any unit. That seems congruent with the "boost conversion rate across all stores" rather than merely on average.

Without statistical computation of significance, we don't know if variants are better due to chance...

@Rage whether you perform such computation or not, it will always remain the case that we don't know whether the measurements of the variants, reflect a true average value/effect or a fluctuation because of chance. The only thing that a statistical computation does is that it gives you an estimate about the probability that an observed conversion rate is close to the true average conversion rate. The goal of such computations is not to perform the optimisation (as the question asks for), but to give information about the quality of the optimisation and optimize the optimization itselve.
